# How to disable google map api v3 anti-aliasing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, antialiasing

I have an image to add to google map using overlay .

- This is my image ( a part of my image ) : [link here](http://postimg.org/image/rsvetpn95/) .
- And this is when it is added to Google map : [link here](http://postimg.org/image/r5wi46qd5/) .

Sorry I don't have enough rep to post image :( .

As you can see, Google makes it smoother but I don't want to do this . I want it look like normal .

How can I do that ? Please help .

P/s : currently there is no way to do this . So sad :( .

Comment: Show us your code; how are you adding the image to the map?

Comment: @duncan : Sorry for late reply . This is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/wtz2svqa/ . It's just a demo because I can not public real image .

Comment: Doesn't look anti-aliased to me

Comment: @duncan : tks for answer . When zoom lv = 15 you will see the problem .

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffswitzer/hhcgyLtb/

Add the following css and the anti-aliasing should go away. I've only tested this in chrome and firefox with a google maps image overlay. Pretty sure it won't work for explorer and that it will work in safari.

```
img {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
}
```

For more info check this [image-rendering MDN Webdoc entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering).